# How fast can an object be made to vibrate?

Tags: time-dilation, faster-than-light, vibrations

Can an object (or system) be made to vibrate so fast, that the vibrational transit speed approaches the speed of light therefor slowing time down significantly for the object or system relative to everything outside?

Comment: theoretically yes.

Comment: practically no.

Comment: Related: [Is the speed of sound almost as high as the speed of light in neutron stars?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54684/123208)